# Comma before "as a token of my gratitude?"

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am writing a little note to a person who returned my lost wallet. Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> Please accept the cash enclosed herein, as a token of my gratitude.

What is confusing me is whether there should be a comma before the phrase "as a  token of my gratitude"

My guess is that as the only cash enclosed is the cash offered as a gift, the information is non crucial, making the phrase non-restrictive clause, and therefore comma would be required.

Comment: I believe you've phrased it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! You can not put a comma before "as a token of my gratitude."

> ***My guess is that as the only cash enclosed is the cash offered as a gift**, the information is non crucial, making the phrase non-restrictive clause, and therefore comma would be required.*

The phrase is a restrictive clause even in your context. "as a token of my gratitude" depends on "Please accept the cash enclosed herein." You cannot offset the first sentence by a comma.

What makes it dependent? The word "as" makes it dependent. It is used as an adverb, not conjunction.

You can say it like the following ways:

> - Please accept the cash enclosed herein, a token of my gratitude.
> - Please accept the cash enclosed herein—a token of my gratitude.
> - <sup>1</sup>As a token of my gratitude, please accept the cash enclosed 
>     herein.

---

<sub>1. When you start or begin a question with a dependent clause, you put a comma after it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you a secret way how I learned how to use punctuation marks. I know this may not be the right way, but often have I found it to be very helpful. 

Read the sentence carefully and see if you can split the sentence into two independent sentences, by appending out the optional part.

> Please accept the cash enclosed herein, as a token of my gratitude.

This can be split into two separate meaningful sentences:

**Please accept the cash enclosed herein.**

and

**Please accept the cash as a token of my gratitude.**

Now when you combine these two sentences, they form your sentence. Now since each event in independent ('enclosing the cash' and 'accepting it as a token of his gratitude'), they can be separated using a comma. This is not the best method, but it may be useful. **Beware, this method doesn't work on all sentences,** but you should try it to see its success rate.